# Angular - controlValueAccessor outside form not being updated by writeValue()

Tags: angular

I have a component with an input that implements ControlValueAccessor, and inside the writeValue I need to make changes to the value that is received from outside.

The change is reflected by the input inside the component, however triggering onChanged initially inside writeValue does not update the main form.

This is the writeValue inside the component:

```
  writeValue(value: string): void {
    if (value) {
      this.value = `${value}-changed`;
      this.onChanged(this.value);
    }
  }
```

This is the parent component

```
<form [formGroup]="schedulerForm">
  <div formGroupName="information">
    <label>Schedule Name <input formControlName="title" /></label>
  </div>

  <div formArrayName="days">
    <div
      class="scheduler-day"
      *ngFor="
        let day of $any(schedulerForm).get('days').controls;
        let dayIndex = index
      "
      [formGroupName]="dayIndex"
    >
      <label>{{ day.value.name }}</label>
      <div formArrayName="timeRanges">
        <div
          class="time-ranges"
          *ngFor="
            let timeRange of $any(day).get('timeRanges').controls;
            let timeRangeIndex = index
          "
          [formGroupName]="timeRangeIndex"
        >
          <app-time-picker formControlName="start"></app-time-picker>
          <app-time-picker formControlName="end"></app-time-picker>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

```
export class FormFieldLabelExample {
  schedulerForm: FormGroup;
  _days: any[] = [
    { Id: 1, Name: 'Mon', TimeRanges: [{ Start: '9:00am', End: '5:00pm' }] },
  ];

  constructor(private readonly _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.schedulerForm = this._formBuilder.group({
      information: this._formBuilder.group({
        title: 'Scheduler',
      }),
      days: new FormArray([]),
    });

    const array = this.schedulerForm.get('days') as FormArray;
    this._days?.forEach((day) => array.push(this.day(day)));
  }

  private day(day?: any): FormGroup {
    const group = this._formBuilder.group({
      name: day?.Name,
      timeRanges: new FormArray([]),
    });

    const array = group.get('timeRanges') as FormArray;
    day.TimeRanges?.forEach((range: any) => array.push(this.timeRange(range)));

    return group;
  }

  private timeRange(range?: any): FormGroup {
    return this._formBuilder.group({
      start: [range?.Start, Validators.required],
      end: [range?.End, Validators.required],
    });
  }
}
```

I have a blur event which triggers onChange and the parent form gets updated, however what am I doing wrong that initially although onChange does fire in writeValue, the parent does not get updated.

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-time-select-dsfdk3-tizazv)